# vb.net How do to display DB values on a listbox?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to do display multiple rows with two column values on a list box so when a user selects an option they have a little extra information.

It should look like this:

```
ej. 3 BestBuy
```

I use the same method to output data to my GridViews but it doesn't display anything on the listbox. What is the correct method to output data from a db to a listbox.

**SQL Control Class Functions**

```
Public Function ExecQuery(query As String) As DataTable

    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(query, DBCon)
        Params.ForEach(Sub(p) DBCmd.Parameters.Add(p))
        Params.Clear()
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return DBDT
End Function

'Add Params
Public Sub AddParam(Name As String, Value As Object)
    Dim NewParam As New SqlParameter(Name, Value)
    Params.Add(NewParam)
End Sub
```

**How im trying to add data to the listbox**

```
Protected Sub DivisionListBox_DataBinding(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DivisionListBox.DataBinding

    Try
        dt = SQL.ExecQuery("Select STR_GRP_ID, GROUP_DESC
                            FROM Store_Group_Desc ")

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Exit Sub
    End Try

    DivisionListBox.DataSource = dt
    DivisionListBox.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Comment: Have a look at DataMember and ValueMember and see if that helps.

Comment: I believe this is an asp.net application. Please add that tag.

Comment: Just keep in mind that a listbox or dropdown can have a PK column, and a display column. But the combo box (drop down) or listbox ONLY has a single column display. The suggested answer below thus will "concentrate" the several columns. As a general rule, combo box and listbox are single column displays. The only wide spread exception is MSAccess which has both multi-column listbox and combo boxes (something i mess in vb.net). For multi-column listbox, then use a data grid, but for the combo box, the the below suggest to use strings that "combine" several columns is about your only choice.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is return the `STR_GRP_ID` as well as create an aliased column that concatenated the `STR_GRP_ID` and `GROUP_DESC` fields.

Then you would bind the DataTable to the ListBox like you're doing but specifying that the ListBox's DisplayMember is your aliased column and the ValueMember is the id:

```vb
Try
    dt = SQL.ExecQuery("Select STR_GRP_ID, CONCAT_WS(' ', STR_GRP_ID, GROUP_DESC GROUP_DESC) AS DisplayText FROM Store_Group_Desc;")
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Return
End Try

With DivisionListBox
    .DataSource = dt
    .DisplayMember = "DisplayText"
    .ValueMember = "STR_GRP_ID"
End With
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `DataBinding` event will ever be triggered in you code. You can set a break point inside the event and see if it is ever triggered.

I chose to use the `Page.Load` event to fill the list box. I separated the user interface code that actually fills the list box from the data access code.

I had the server do the work to build the string your want to display.  I assumed the id field was some type of number field so I cast it to a varchar. Then added a space and the description field. This new select field is called IDDesc.

IDDesc is the field name that I want to display in the list box.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        FillListBox()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub FillListBox()
    Dim ListBoxData = GetListBoxData()
    ListBox1.DataTextField = "IDDesc"
    ListBox1.DataSource = ListBoxData
    ListBox1.DataBind()
End Sub

Private Function GetListBoxData() As DataTable
    Dim DBDT = New DataTable
    Dim Query = "Select Cast(STR_GRP_ID As varchar) + ' ' + GROUP_DESC As IDDesc
                        FROM Store_Group_Desc "
    Using DBCon As New SqlConnection(ConStr),
            DBCmd As New SqlCommand(Query, DBCon)
        DBCon.Open()
        DBDT.Load(DBCmd.ExecuteReader)
    End Using
    Return DBDT
End Function
```